# IDAPython Get Function Parameter Type Name

Tags: ida, idapython

I'm currently trying to make a hotkey to rename example functions `sub_123450(aType* this, void* a2)` to `aType::123450(aType* this, void* a2)`. I have code to rename etc. but how can I get the name of the type of the arguments to the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func_ea = 0x123450  # sub_123450


tif = ida_typeinf.tinfo_t()
funcdata = ida_typeinf.func_type_data_t()

assert ida_nalt.get_tinfo(tif, func_ea)
assert tif.get_func_details(funcdata)

for pos, argument in enumerate(funcdata):
    print(f'argument {pos + 1}: {argument.type}{argument.name}')
```

This should give you:

```
argument 1: aType* this
argument 2: void* a2
```